# In angularjs how to submit a form with disabled fields

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I have a form in angularjs which have certain input text fields and a checkbox.
If the checkbox is selected then it will disable some certain fields in the form but the value will remain visible, so that, if user deselected the checkbox then, he doesn't have to fill those fields again. However, I don't want to submit the values of the disabled fields when user submits the form.

Comment: Do you want to submit the form "with disabled fields" OR "without disabled field values"? Title and details are asking for different requirements.

Answer (score -1):

I'll list 3 ways, by the order i would suggest:

1. submit it whole, and disregard the excessive data Server Side.
   i assume the "disabled" data is not too big to affect performance.
2. process the form data before submission.
   run Javascript `onSubmit()` `$(form).find('input[disabled]').value(null);`
   (hope my jQuery syntax is correct.)
3. least recommended, instead of just disable the inputs, you can set `input.placeholder = input.value; input.value = '';` and the opposite when you re-enable it.

Comment: @wickY26 you can use jQuery on an Angular scoped `submit` handler though

Comment: of course you can use a jQuery but it is not advised and you should misdirect a people with little knowledge about angularjs...

Comment: translate the jQuery to pure JS i'd say.